# DynamoDB many to one

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to come up with a solution for the item versioning table.
Let's say we have an existing table *items* with records and PK is *items.shop_uuid* SK *items.item_uuid* + some attributes, to simplify it let's have a single column called *"data"*.

I thought to have versions be part of the *"data"*, but then I won't be able to query by version uuid. And I need to create some Secondary Index to access the same record by *shop_uuid* and *version_uuid*.

The question is, how to structure the table to use access pattern *shop_uuid* and any *version_uuid* that belongs to an *item_uuid* so I could get the same record?

Or should I version with the original access pattern (shop_uuid + item_uuid) and just make dynamo requests transactional to avoid any integrity issue?

Answer (score 0):

| pk | sk | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shop_uuid | item_uuid#V000 | {} |
| shop_uuid | item_uuid#V001 | {} |
| shop_uuid | item_uuid#V002 | {} |
| shop_uuid | item_uuid#V003 | {} |

To get the latest version of an item simply:

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE PK = shop_uuid and SK begins_with(item_uuid) Limit 1 DESC`

Alternatively, you could implement a method discussed in this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-version-control-using-amazon-dynamodb/)

Comment: Doesn't feel right, as I understand "begins_with" operation would trigger a scan within the shop and leads to poor performance and high cost.

Comment: It's a Query operation which is highly efficient and performant. It's the best way to model your use-case.